# Unable to turn of screen while making WhatsApp or skype call on loudspeaker ios 10 update

Tags: iphone, skype, ios, whatsapp.app

Usually, when I make a Skype or WhatsApp call, while talking, I will switch off the display to conserve the battery as well as my eyes without the need to stare at the screen. This would allow the call to continue without any interruptions. However, since updating to iOS 10, turning off the display disconnects the Skype or WhatsApp call. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Exchange.

1. This doesn't happen to me on my phone, so it must be a bug or something ...
   I wonder if this is similar to this issue: [Unable to turn of screen while making WhatsApp call on loudspeaker io10 update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253407/unable-to-turn-of-screen-while-making-whatsapp-call-on-loudspeaker-io10-update?rq=1)
2. have you tried closing the apps and restarting the phone?  You can quit the apps by double-tapping the home button, swiping the app UP (I would do this with WhatsApp and Skype), and then holding the power button until the option to turn the phone off comes up - swiping on that, and then starting the phone back up?
3. try a forced restart of the phone.  Hold the home and power buttons until the phone just seems to shut off; continue holding until the Apple comes up.
4. I would backup the phone, wipe it, and restore from the backup.